# Add headerView to listView in widget on widget resize android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-widget

I would like to implement widget with a `ListView` and when the user resizes the widget, then I would like to add a header on the list. I want to achieve something like this:

1. This is initial `WidgetView`:
   [image: expected result]
2. This I like to achieve when user resize the widget:
   [image: expected result on resizing]

Here is the code for the layout:

This is layout for row item (list_row.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Heading"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/heading"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code for the initial layout of the widget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewWidget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code for the layout of the header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lay2">
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Header List View"
    android:textColor="@color/pink"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code for meta data for the widget:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:minHeight="40dip"
    android:minWidth="40dip"
    android:resizeMode="vertical|horizontal"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
    >
</appwidget-provider>
```

Here is the code for widget provider:

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions) {
    //super.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, newOptions);

    // See the dimensions and
    Bundle options = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(appWidgetId);

    // Get min width and height.
    int minWidth = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH);
    int minHeight = options.getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT);

    // Obtain appropriate widget and update it.
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, getRemoteViews(context, minWidth, minHeight));
    super.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, newOptions);
}

private RemoteViews getRemoteViews(Context context, int minWidth, int minHeight) {
    // First find out rows and columns based on width provided.
    int rows = getCellsForSize(minHeight);
    int columns = getCellsForSize(minWidth);
    // Now you changing layout base on you column count
    // In this code from 1 column to 4
    // you can make code for more columns on your own.
    switch (rows) {
        case 1:  return new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        case 2:
            //return new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_layout_widget_4column);
            RemoteViews update2 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.text_view_layout);
            //for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            RemoteViews textView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
                //textView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, "TextView number " + String.valueOf(i));
            update2.addView(R.id.lay2, textView);
            //}

            return update2;
        case 3:
            //return new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_layout_widget_4column);
            RemoteViews update3 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.text_view_layout);
            //for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            RemoteViews textView1 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            //textView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, "TextView number " + String.valueOf(i));
            update3.addView(R.id.lay2, textView1);
            //}

            return update3;
        case 4:
            //return new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_layout_widget_4column);
            RemoteViews update4 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.text_view_layout);
            //for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            RemoteViews textView3 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            //textView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, "TextView number " + String.valueOf(i));
            update4.addView(R.id.lay2, textView3);
            //}

            return update4;

        default: return null;
    }
}

private static int getCellsForSize(int size) {
    int n = 2;
    while (70 * n - 30 < size) {
        ++n;
    }
    return n - 1;
}


@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context,
                appWidgetIds[i]);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i],
                remoteViews);
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

}

private RemoteViews updateWidgetListView(Context context,
                                         int appWidgetId) {

    //which layout to show on widget
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(
            context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);

    //RemoteViews Service needed to provide adapter for ListView
    Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
    //passing app widget id to that RemoteViews Service
    svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    //setting a unique Uri to the intent
    //don't know its purpose to me right now
    svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(
            svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    //setting adapter to listview of the widget
    remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.listViewWidget,
            svcIntent);
    return remoteViews;
}
}
```

Here is the code for the `WidgetService`:

```
public class WidgetService extends RemoteViewsService{

    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(
            AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        return (new ListProvider(this.getApplicationContext(), intent));
    }
}
```

Here is the code for `ListProvider`:

```
public class ListProvider implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory{
    private ArrayList listItemList = new ArrayList();
    private Context context = null;
    private int appWidgetId;

    public ListProvider(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
            AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        populateListItem();
    }

    private void populateListItem() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
            listItem.heading = "Heading" + i;
            listItem.content = i + " This is the content of the app widget listview.Nice content though";
            listItemList.add(listItem);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listItemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /*
    *Similar to getView of Adapter where instead of View
    *we return RemoteViews
    *
    */
    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        final RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(
            context.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_row);
        ListItem listItem = (ListItem)listItemList.get(position);
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.heading, listItem.heading);
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.content, listItem.content);
        return remoteView;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for `ListItem`:

```
public class ListItem {
    public String heading,content;
}
```

However on resize I get this result:

[image]

`ListView` is gone. Do anyone has idea why?

Answer (score 0):

My list view is empty because in the method `getRemoteViews` I create new RemoteViews and I didn't fill it at all. So I made some changes to the code above:

```
private RemoteViews getRemoteViews(Context context, int minWidth, int minHeight, int appWidgetId) {
    int rows = getCellsForSize(minHeight);
    int columns = getCellsForSize(minWidth);
    switch (rows) {
        case 1:  return new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        case 2:
            RemoteViews update2 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.text_view_layout);
            RemoteViews textView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            update2.addView(R.id.lay2, textView); 
            Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
            svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(
                    svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
            update2.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.listViewWidget,
                    svcIntent);
            return update2;
        case 3:
            RemoteViews update3 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.text_view_layout);
            RemoteViews textView1 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            update3.addView(R.id.lay2, textView1);
            Intent svcIntent1 = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
            svcIntent1.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            svcIntent1.setData(Uri.parse(
                    svcIntent1.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
            update3.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.listViewWidget,
                    svcIntent1);
            return update3;
        case 4:
            RemoteViews update4 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.text_view_layout);
            RemoteViews textView3 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            update4.addView(R.id.lay2, textView3);
            Intent svcIntent2 = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
            svcIntent2.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
            svcIntent2.setData(Uri.parse(
            svcIntent2.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
            update4.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.listViewWidget,
                    svcIntent2);
            return update4;

        default: return null;
    }
}
```